# How to create a WP_Query to search the Title or Tag?

Tags: php, wp-query, query, search, tax-query

I have created a search using WP_Query, it seems like this query is looking for the queried term in title AND tags.

Is there a way to have this search the title OR tags?

```
$s = $request['s'];
$tags = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($request['s']));

$paged = $request['page'];
$posts_per_page = $request['per_page'];

$result = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category__in'      => 3060,
    'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page,
    'paged'             => $page,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'desc',
    's'                 => $s,
    'tag'               => array($tags)
]);
```

Comment: Do you want to search in tags, or treat the search query as potential slug of tag?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to show posts in texonomy and titles

```
$s = $request['s'];
$tags = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($request['s']));

$q1 = get_posts(array(
        'fields' => 'id',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' =>  $s 

));
 $q2 = get_posts(array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tag' => array($tags)
));
$unique = array_unique( array_merge( $q1, $q2 ) );

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $unique,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
  if ($posts ) : 

foreach( $posts as $post ) :
//show results
endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: The only problem is that you do not perform search in tag titles, but in tag slugs. And when I think of "searching in tags", most probably I have tag names on my mind... But maybe it's just me.

Comment: This almost worked for me, except the `array_unique` part. I had to use a second parameter of that function, like this:

```$unique = array_unique( array_merge( $q1, $q2), SORT_REGULAR);
$uniqueIds = array_map(function ($post){
    return $post->ID;
}, $unique);

$args['post__in'] = $uniqueIds;
```

otherwise I was getting "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string" error.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add

```
 'relation' => 'OR'
```

in your Query arguments.
add it and it will return the data with OR condition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This only works with in a few cases, such as [taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).